# Vim: See all instances on page and choose one

Tags: search, vim, plugins

I seem to recall a vim plugin that will allow you to, essentially, execute ":g/pattern/p" and then prompt you to select one.  Does anyone know of this plugin?  Or is it a built-in function?

Basically, I want to perform a search, see all instances on the current page (or even in open buffers), and then be able to select which one to go to.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I want it to actually take me to the line number when I make my selection, and I want it to be a fairly simple solution.  I'm pretty sure I've seen a plugin for this, but I can't remember what it was.  Any thoughts?

PS. Thank you to all who are answering.  They're great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:vim[grep]` or `:gr[ep]`.

```
:vim foo % | cw
```

[image: :vim foo % | cw]

See `:help quickfix`.

If you want a plugin, you'll have to search vim.org.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've seen a plugin that brings up this list, and then allows you to make a selection and takes you to the line in question.  I just can't seem to find it or remember anything else about it.

Comment: Why would you need a plugin? You can do everything you ask with built-in commands. Once the quickfix list is opened you can navigate it and hit `<CR>` on a result to jump to it and so on. Read the part of the doc I've given to you.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you close. Its not an interactive menu but it does tell you the line number for the match

```
:g/<regex>/#
```

The `#`  tell global to print the line numbers. Take a look at `:h :number` (`#` is a synonym for `:number`)

Comment: It actually shows me line numbers without the #.  What I want is an ordered selection I can choose from.  I know there's a plugin that will prompt you for selection, I just can't remember what it was...

Comment: @MrA mine does not show the line numbers. I guess you have `:set number` already in your vimrc which also seems to show you the line numbers

Answer (score 2):

You could populate the result into the `quickfix` window via the `:vimgrep` command

```
:vimgrep/regex/ %
```

`%` represents the current buffer's filename. Note: buffer must be a file and not a scratch buffer.

Then use `quickfix` commands like `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move through the list. Or open the list via `:copen` and press `<cr>` to jump to the match.

You can `:vimgrep` any number of files:

- All `*.c` files e.g. `:vimgrep/regex/ *.c`.
- Use `**` to search down into deep directories e.g. `:vimgrep/regex/ **/*.c`.

You can also use `vimgrep` with the args list via `:vimgrep/regex/ ##`.

For more help see:

```
:h :vimgrep
:h quickfix
:h c_%
:h arglist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:g/regex/p
```

`:g` executes `:p` by default, so it can be omitted; the trailing slash can also be dropped:

```
:g/regex
```

Note that `:g` jumps to the last occurrence in the file, so you can then execute `N/` (in normal mode) to jump to the Nth occurrence. Or, if there are many matches and you don't care to count which one you want, you can at least jump to its line, L, with `LG` or `Lgg` or `:L`.

If you don't use `:set number` but want line numbers in the output of `:p`, append `nu[mber]` or `#` as @FDinoff suggests:

```
:g/regex/nu
:g/regex/#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm one change after another in all open buffers with:

```
:bufdo %s;<pattern>;<replace>;c | update
```

The `:bufdo` goes through all buffers.  The `c` is the flag to confirm all changes.  The `update` writes the current buffer which allows going to the next.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the question at all?